# Programmatically disable app power saving mode on Samsung

Tags: android

I am the developer of a messaging application. My application get put on an automatic power save mode which prevents messages from getting through.

When I go to the App Power Saving option on a Samsung phone (Settings->Battery->App Power Saving option), I can see that this option is "Disabled" for certain apps (like WhatsApp and Facebook messenger).

When I do a clean install of the WhatsApp application, the power saving mode gets disabled by default before I even open the app.

This seems to be specific to Samsung devices Android version 6.0.1 and higher.

Is it possible to disable power saving by default for my application?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: No sorry, I haven't.

Comment: I think that WhatsApp and Facebook messenger are on the OS white list.

Comment: Use cloud messaging with high priority to reach your application when power saving is enabled. I think @netpork is right that there is a special place in Samsungs hell for WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetD destroys sockets when device is not connected to charger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721418/netd-destroys-sockets-when-device-is-not-connected-to-charger)

Comment: Hi I was solving the same issue, this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48763927/4606542

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask user to ignore battery optimizations: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases

But your use case needs to be acceptable for Google Play validation: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases

Comment: this isn't the same thing