# Oppo firebase notification in background

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, oppo

Code for permission oppo cannot load app. Oppo phone cannot handle notification in background, 
but when I use these code it work well:

```
val POWERMANAGER_INTENTS = arrayOf(
        Intent().setComponent(
            ComponentName(
                "com.coloros.safecenter",
                "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"
            )
        ),
        Intent().setComponent(
            ComponentName(
                "com.coloros.safecenter",
                "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity"
            )
        )
    )
```

But this code cause my app cannnot load. it's make error like that:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firebasesms.hong/com.firebasesms.hong.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent.......

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent ..... requires oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE
```

AndroidManifest

[image]

Code: Kotlin

[image]

Error: requires oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need "OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" permission into your manifest to start Intent.

```
    <!--for OPPO-->
<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" />
```

Reference: [Denial permission OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814755/denial-permission-oppo-component-safe)