# In android version 8.0 I used work manager to fire a broadcast on periodic time, But when I clear an app from recent tasks It is not working

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have set a work manager to do task at specific time periodically. But It is working with other android version like 25 or lower. When I run it on API 28 It is going to stop firing a broadcast when I clear app from recent lists.

I have scheduled work manager like this in activity :

```
 OneTimeWorkRequest mywork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class).setInitialDelay(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mywork);
```

This is my Worker class :

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {
        // Do the work here
        Mylogger.getInstance().printLog("MyWorr","doWork()");
        //fire broadcast from here
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimeMatchingBroadcastReceiver.class);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        CommonUtils.scheduleWorkManager();
        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

I want execute work manager even when I close or clear app from recent list on all version of android.
Thanks.

Comment: Telling by your `return WorkerResult.SUCCESS` I think you are not using the latest version. Try updating to latest version (currently I think it is beta05').

Comment: @Ridcully Thanks for your suggestion. Let me update and test it.

Comment: @Ridcully previous  issue is solved by incresing version of work lib. `But now it is not working On model Xiaomi MI 5. API level 28 (8.0.0)` When I clear app from recent list. Can you please help me about it.

Comment: I guess it's best, if you file a bug for WorkManager. According to the release notes of the various beta versions, they seem to fix a lot of bugs like that for various Android versions.

Answer (score 7):

As per the ankuranurag2 answer it is true that some android brands are force stopping the application after killing from the recent.
check this issue in the work manager google issue tracker 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110745313 for tag #2 .

Even I am also tried to run the job in background after killing app from recent (device - HUAWEI BKL-L09) but not able to do that.

Checked for the auto launch option after changing it to manually then it was working fine.
But this is not a good idea to for UX to tell the user to change the auto launch option and we cant able to find whether it is on or off.

After searching I have given a patch fix, I think it is not a better solution but can check it is working for me.

1st Create a service which identifies killing the app process 
I refered to this url
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856811/8264148

UserKillingService

```
class UserKillingService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?)= null

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int)= Service.START_NOT_STICKY

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        val i = Intent(this,StartUpActivity::class.java)
        i!!.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        i!!.putExtra("USER_KILLED", "USER_KILLED")
        startActivity(i)
        //stop the service
        stopSelf()
    }
}
```

Configure the service in manifest

```
<service android:name=".UserKillingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

This Service calls the StartUpActivity in onTaskRemoved and Stops the service which is not required at all.

this activity is a main launcher activity with no UI

```
StartUpActivity

<activity android:name=".StartUpActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

or you can use android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

```
Inside onCreate of StartUpActivity

if (intent.hasExtra("USER_KILLED")) {
//finish the instance
            finish()
        } else {
          SplashActivity::class.start(this@StartUpActivity,finish = true)
        }
```

This Startupactivity will finish without force stop the application.
This activity calls splashActivity when it is not triggered from UserKillingService.

Inside SplashActivity onCreate call the UserKillingService

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startService(Intent(baseContext,UserKillingService::class.java))
```

Please tell me if you get any better solution. Sorry for my english

Comment: Tested it on Android 8 (Oreo). Works flawlessly :thums-up:. But I have 1 question. Why do you have the check for "SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O" before starting the service?

Comment: @MarkKowalski Because the devices which are restricted for battery optimization is above Nougat. You can check this video regarding android workmanager. they are trying to fix this by contacting manufacturers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qxj2eBmXLHg&t=1354s

Comment: Tested on Android 10 (R). Works very well! Really smart trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you go through [THE LINK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110745313), you will find:

> Unfortunately, some devices implement killing the app from the recents menu as a force stop.  Stock Android does not do this.  When an app is force stopped, it cannot execute jobs, receive alarms or broadcasts, etc.  So unfortunately, it's infeasible for us to address it - the problem lies in the OS and there is no workaround.

It is a known issue. To save battery, many manufacturers force close the app, thus cancelling all the period tasks, alarms and broadcast recievers etc. Major manufacturers being OnePlus(you have option to toogle),Redmi,Vivo,Oppo,Huwaei.

Each of these devices have AutoStartManagers/AutoLaunch/StartManager type of optimization managers. Which prevent the background activities to start again. You will have to manually ask the user to whitelist your application, so that app can auto start its background processess. Follow [THIS](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793) and [THIS](https://support.kayako.com/article/1461-why-aren-t-push-notifications-working-on-my-android-app) link, for more info.

**The methods to add to whitelist for different manufactures are give in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641229/7976274). Even after adding to whitelist, your app might not work because of DOZE Mode, for that you will have to [ignore battery otimizations](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/24632/whitelisting-an-android-application-programmatically)**

Also in case you might be wondering, apps like Gmail/Hangout/WhatsApp/Slack/LinkedIn etc are already whitelisted by these AutoStart Managers. Hence, there is no effect on their background processes. You always receive timely updates & notifications.

P.S: Copied from my own answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54326607/7976274)