# How to Enable Autostart option programmatically in Samsung devices?

Tags: android

I am using the background services and it does not run on some devices as I have to enable the autostart permission for the app. I want to enable the autostart permission automatically where it needs. I am using this code but it redirects me on the window where the autostart permission is. But in samsung mobiles it is not directing to that window

```
  if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                alertdialogue(intent);
            } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
                alertdialogue(intent);
            } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
                alertdialogue(intent);
            } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
                alertdialogue(intent);
            } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
                alertdialogue(intent);
            }
```

i want solution for samsung devices

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are right in saying that `com.samsung.android.sm` is the package name on N/7.0/24 and above, however I have found that on Q/10.0/29 the activity name has changed from `com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity` to `com.samsung.android.sm.battery.ui.BatteryActivity`. I'm not sure about O or P. Best thing is to simply make a list of all the possible resolutions and try them in turn:

```
fun openSamsungBackgroundSettings() {

    val possibleIntents = mutableListOf<Intent>()
    val battery1 = "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"
    val battery2 = "com.samsung.android.sm.battery.ui.BatteryActivity"
    val pkg = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        "com.samsung.android.lool"
    else
        "com.samsung.android.sm"
    possibleIntents.add(Intent().setComponent(ComponentName(pkg, battery1)))
    possibleIntents.add(Intent().setComponent(ComponentName(pkg, battery2)))
    //general settings as backup
    possibleIntents.add(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))
    possibleIntents.forEach {
        try {
            startActivity(it)
            return
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            w(ex){"Failed to open intent:$it"}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.samsung.android.lool","com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"))

try this intent, but this is for taking to battery optimisation control activity,
didnt found exact AutoStart intend for Samsung, if you find then let me know please

Comment: I also didn't find any solution. Please tell me if u know and also tell about infinix mobiles

Answer (score 0):

there is some Samsung mobile who don't support this authorization (dont have an activity for battery optimization)
however for those who have there is two case

`"com.samsung.android.sm", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"` on Android L

`"com.samsung.android.lool", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"` on Android N