# Как запустить экран настроек приложения на huawei?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, huawei-developers, xiaomi

I need to check the boxes in the application settings on xiaomi it works an error appears on Huawei.

[image: Load]
My code:

```
try
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetComponent("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity"); // huawei
                // intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.appmanager.ApplicationsDetailsActivity")); // xiaomy
                intent.PutExtra("package_name", PackageName);

                StartActivity(intent); 

            }
            catch (Exception anfe)
            {
            }
```

My Exception

```
{Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.huawei.systemmanager/.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2f6f6d7 8007:com.companyname.corporate_messenger/u0a410} (pid=8007, uid=10410) requires com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT ---> Android.OS.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1209)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:924)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:674)
    at com.android.server.wm.HwActivityStarter.startActivity(HwActivityStarter.java:278)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1737)
callee: null 1665/2209

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <00c315a988634383b446eff646084784>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <00c315a988634383b446eff646084784>:0 
  at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.StartActivity (Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x00027] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-29/mcw/Android.Content.ContextWrapper.cs:3364 
  at Corporate_messenger.Droid.MainActivity.SetPermission (System.String param1, System.String param2) [0x00028] in D:\Project\Xamarin\Messanger\Corporate messenger\Corporate messenger.Android\MainActivity.cs:103 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.SecurityException stack trace ---
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.huawei.systemmanager/.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2f6f6d7 8007:com.companyname.corporate_messenger/u0a410} (pid=8007, uid=10410) requires com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2091)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2059)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2007)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3908)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1738)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5412)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5337)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5819)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5787)
    at crc6480b75fa72058fc63.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc6480b75fa72058fc63.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8214)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8202)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4033)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4247)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2613)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1209)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:924)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:674)
    at com.android.server.wm.HwActivityStarter.startActivity(HwActivityStarter.java:278)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1737)
callee: null 1665/2209

}
```

the application could open this page on its own.Basically , this problem occurs on huawei phone. At the moment I am writing an application for android. But xamarin allows you to write code for iOS, so in the future I will also add such functions there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it tells you right there, on huawei you are missing a permission:

> {Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
> cmp=com.huawei.systemmanager/.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity
> (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2f6f6d7
> 8007:com.companyname.corporate_messenger/u0a410} (pid=8007, uid=10410)
> requires **com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT**
> ---> Android.OS.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:

So I'm guessing add this permission to your Manifest or programmatically request it when you detect you are on huawei phone.

Comment: How do I register it in the manifest? more precisely, what should this line look like

Comment: Check the marked answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166206/how-to-start-power-manager-of-all-android-manufactures-to-enable-background-and

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT" />

But it's not helps.