# NetD destroys sockets when device is not connected to charger

Tags: java, android

I have a quite annoying Problem and I don't understand what is happening:

We are writing a library, that builds up a socket via Bluetooth. After that, we register a server on localhost.  Now several apps are establishing a connection to localhost and send/receive data. The server is bundling the connections and handles the communication over Bluetooth.

We are encountering this problem since Android 7.0; `NetD` is destroying our sockets to localhost frequently. The following output we can see in Logcat:

```
>     06-23 12:38:17.576   522  2676 I Netd    : Destroyed 3 sockets for UidRanges{ 10000-2147483647 } skip={1001 1027 10010 10013 10018 10021
> 10035 10037 10064 10081} in 1.2 ms
```

All devices are running Stock Roms and I tested it on the following:

- Samsung S7
- Samsung S8
- Nexus 5x
- Samsung S6
- Google Pixel

I'm quite sure, that it is a battery save mechanism, as it does not happen while charging the device.

I hope anybody can help me understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from the new `Doze` feature that was introduced in Android 6.0 API Level 23, [enhanced in Android 7.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html).

> Doze improves battery life by deferring CPU and network activities
>   when a user leaves a device unplugged, stationary, and with the screen
>   turned off. Android 7.0 brings further enhancements to Doze by
>   applying a subset of CPU and network restrictions while the device is
>   unplugged with the screen turned off, but not necessarily stationary,
>   for example, when a handset is traveling in a user’s pocket.

**Doze restrictions**

The following restrictions apply to your apps while in Doze:

- Network access is suspended.
- The system ignores wake locks.
- Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.

  - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
  - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.
- The system does not perform Wi-Fi scans.
- The system does not allow sync adapters to run.
- The system does not allow JobScheduler to run

With that said, you technically have two options - embrace Doze, fight it.

**Embracing Doze**

Go over [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

**Fighting Doze**

A combination of `dumpsys deviceidle disable`, setting `idle_to` and `max_idle_to` to 1 sec (and associated scaling factors to 1) will help in disabling it. Refer to this [xda-developers post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/root-doze-settings-editor-android-t3235130/page138).

Comment: Glad I could help!